# Optimize ruby bot for heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Currently I have a ruby on rails bot that calls a method in the view and runs that method as a infinite loop and that is how the bot continues its actions indefinitely. At the end of the loop there is a delay for 2 hours or so where it sleeps. Currently I have a few problems:

1) I can't run this bot forever because it never loads a page since its running the infinite loop and heroku has a 30 second time-out policy you can't change.

2) I can fix this by making the method run on a worker dyno. But the method I am using with sleep causes the dyno to run continuously.

The question is: Is there a way to structure my app on heroku so that it has a delay that doesn't use the dyno hours? I want to be able to continue to automatically run the bot in some fashion on two dynos (1 web and 1 worker) and still stay within the 750 free hours allotted by heroku. Any help is greatly appreciate!

Comment: Change your bot/app so that instead of loading one endless page, bot will load endless number of smaller pages. That is, move the loop to bot logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Heroku Scheduler plug-in to run your worker task on a schedule (once every two hours, perhaps?). Then you can yank out the sleep() call, and just let the bot exit normally when it completes whatever it is that it's doing.